# AR place an object with same size

Tags: unity-game-engine, mapbox, augmented-reality

I am building an AR application. I have some points which are real worlds coordinates.

I can geolocate these points through Mapbox. My problem is that when I got far away from the points, they are looking getting smaller. I want to see them as the same size independently from the distance.

Here is an example of how to visualize the points:
[image]

So, if I near the points I see them in normal sizes. Even though I got 400 KMs away from the point, I want to see it in the same size. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to scale the lables by some value * distance to object. 
If you are standing in *device* and the target is in *target* it would be:

```c#
float experimentalScale = 0.5f
```

This is the amplifier of the distance. If you increase the value, the lable will get bigger by greater distance. Try out what works best for you.

```c#
float scaleFactor = Vector3.Distance(device.transform.position, target.transform.position) * experimentalScale;

target.transform.localScale(scaleFactor,scaleFactor,scaleFactor)
```

This only works if your Objects scale is `1`. If it is something else, just multiply the scale with `scaleFactor`.

Comment: Thank you it worked. But I have another question. I have 30 points and I have 1 model. I want to scale them differently. When I tried your answer the all points scaled one size, not differently. So, I need 30 different models for 30 points?

Comment: @buğracoşkun well 30 individual scales => you need 30 individual models yes! If the answer solves your question please mark it as accepted